# I have installed jupyter notebook (wind 10) with pip, but when I type jupyter notebook in cmd.exe I get "nonrecognized"

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed jupyter notebook (wind 10) with pip, but when I type jupyter notebook in cmd.exe I get "nonrecognized as internal command"

Comment: 'jupyter notebook' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes

Comment: Consider adding bin directory of jupyter to your PATH environment variable in order to launch jupyter notebook or jupyter lab. Here is an [example](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/)